# How do I eliminate the credential requirements on my development machine

Tags: ssrs-2008

I've got SQL Server 2008 with SSIS/SSRS installed on my development box. I followed through the installation notes and everything appeared to install just fine - no errors or anything.  I've got it configured using all the defaults for now until I figure out what is what. So the server can be accessed via http://localhost:80/ReportServer and the reports via http://locahost:80/Reports.

I've created a dummy report against the AdventureWorks database to test report creation and deployment and after some initial headaches which were resolved by running BIDS as an administrator, I'm having problems accessing the reports via the web interface and indeed, I'm having the same issue accessing the report server via the web interface.

When I open the URLs in any browser - IE/Firefox/Chrome they all prompt me for credentials.  My dev box isn't part of a domain and the credentials I use to log into the machine don't appear to be what it is after as they don't connect successfully. I don't really understand why it's asking for credentials at all due to the fact that the address is an intranet address. In either case, IE is configured to pass through my Windows credentials when logging into machines on the intranet.

Did I configure something incorrectly when I set it up? Does anyone have any decent tutorials for not only installing SSRS, but configuration for development machines.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your browser with elevated (Administrator) privelages. Did that help?

This may also be related...
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lukaszp/archive/2008/07/18/reporting-services-http-401-unauthorized-host-headers-require-your-attention.aspx